# Php class with statc function to connect to database

Tags: pdo

I have this class to connect to my database, but when I try to use it, always return null.

if I use these credentials in a single php file without class and static function, it works.

This is how I use it

```
<?php
include 'bdconexion.php';
$var ="hola";

$pdo=BaseDatos::Conectar();


print '<h3>PDO: simple select</h3>';
foreach($pdo->query( 'SELECT * FROM productos;' ) as $row)
{
echo $row['descripcion'];
}
```

Some help will be great

```
class BaseDatos
{
    private static $bdname = 'bd';
    private static $bdhost = 'localhost';
    private static $user = 'root';
    private static $pass = 'pass';
    //private static $mssqldriver = '{SQL Server}';
    //private static $mssqldriver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}';
    //private static $mssqldriver = '{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}';

    private static $conn = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        die('La funcion de inicio no es permitida');
    }
    public static function conectar()
    {
        if (null==self::$conn) {
            try {

                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".self::$bdhost.";dbname=".self::$bdname,self::$user,self::$pass);

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return self::$conn;
    }

    public static function desconectar()
    {
        self::$conn=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your "usage" part?

Comment: I already edit it @David

Comment: Do you realize you commented out the assignment of the static conn?

Comment: There was one commented, but this one was uncommented, i erased the others, still doesn't work

Comment: try changing $conn = new PDO... to self::conn ...

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem